# STM32 HAL UART RXNE interrupt not generated

Tags: interrupt, stm32, uart, hal

I'm using HAL drivers with code generated by CubeMX. In main routine I called `HAL_UART_Receive_IT()`. After transmitting data over UART (which is connected in a loopback fashion) I can see the module is receiving byte and setting RXNE bit in registers. However interrupt is not generated? I can't explain why... In `HAL_UART_Receive_IT()` function there is code enabling interrupts, so what's wrong?

Comment: It is somewhat tricky to guess without the specific code, my suggestion would be to peek at the I/O register settings in the debugger to spot oddities in the initialization and if that fails extract a minimal repro case with direct register writes to post here. Anyway, can you elaborate on how you know that the interrupt is not being issued? Have you verified that interrupt vector is properly routed and that interrupts have not been masked globally?

Answer (score 6):

You are not giving enough info and code in your question.
Anyway, in your stm32xx_hal_msp.c file you initialize your peripheral from hardware point of view: be sure to enable interrupts too

```
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART1_IRQn, 0, 1);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);
```

Then add

```
void USART1_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart1);
}
```

to your stm32xx_it.c file

Answer (score 0):

I just met a similar problem,and finally find the reason:
I  put a jlink debugger breakpoint at wrong place,The debugger has already read out uart data,which will automatically reset rxne register,and then the code in irq handler will ignore uart data.
so,I reset debugger and mcu,kill all breakpoints,put the only one breakpoint behind in the irq handler,this time,it successfully catched the uart data.